# Why do we use "target_id" as the name of the index in php instead of "entity_id"?

Tags: 7

I'm finding that while I'm coding that I type in things like $entity->field_fieldname['und'][0]['entity_id'] and that this doesn't work.  When the Drupal 7 developers were developing it, why did they select 'target_id' as the index instead of 'entity_id' (or even better, why not try eid? ) I don't know how to contact the Drupal Coders who made this decision, do does anyone know who made this decision?

Drupal 7 has become quite harder to write code in.

Is there a better way for me to be coding that would avoid this problem?

Comment: You'd need to ask the module maintainers why they chose that particular value, we can't really speculate here

Answer (score 2):

target_id is generally used in entity references.  So if you have an entity reference to another entity the target_id is the id of that entity.  This depends if it is a node or an entity though.  But I will mention that generally you want to avoid `$entity->field_fieldname['und'][0]['entity_id']` but instead using the [entity_metadata_wrapper](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7) to target values instead:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

$mytitle = $node_wrapper->title // Title
$myfield = $node_wrapper->field_my_field->value(); // Value of the field, cleaner

You can also use the set method
$node_wrapper->field_my_field->set("My value"); // If single value

$node_wrapper->save(); // Save my entity
```

Comment: Except that using entity_metadata_wrapper is a huge pain. If you want to try to access the target_id of a multi-valued property, for example, there is literally no example on how to do that. I just spent hours searching. If you try to print debug info to find out, you just get a bunch of useless metadata. Using the entity without the wrapper is so much easier.

Comment: Your comment is a bit subjective. Multi valued properties are simple arrays and you can access them and iterate through them. The documentation is clear here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers under working with lists.

Comment: Only if you already know what you're looking for. If you're going from the database, and trying to access a specific column and you don't know what the property is called in the object, it's nearly impossible to figure it out using dpm().